# Derby DB , How to find the date nearest to current Date in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, derby

I am working on a project that is using JDBC (Derby driver), The part of the table details are provided below.

Table Name : Example (

- RID Char(5) Primary Key
- RTime TIME NOT NULL,
- RDate Date NOT NULL

)

I know how to find the closest date to current date (or time) using MAX, but in WHERE condition, MAX and MIN definitely do not work in most SQL.

How can I find the date/time nearest to current date/time in Derby db?

Answer (score 1):

You could either do it with a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE RTime = (SELECT MAX(RTime) FROM T) AND RDate = ...
```

or by sorting on the RDate and RTime columns and selecting the first.